# Javascript the Definitive Guide: the confusion of steps of converting object to a string

Tags: javascript, tostring

According to the section 3.8.3 in the book Javascript the Definitive Guide 6th edition:

> To convert an object to a string, JavaScript takes these steps:
>   • If the object has a `toString()` method, JavaScript calls it. If it returns a primitive value, JavaScript converts that value to a string (if it is not already a string) and returns the result of that conversion. Note that primitive-to-string conversions are all well-defined in Table 3-2.
>
> • If the object has no `toString()` method, or if that method does not return a primitive value, then JavaScript looks for a `valueOf()` method. If the method exists, JavaScript calls it. If the return value is a primitive, JavaScript converts that value to a string (if it is not already) and returns the converted value.
>
> • Otherwise, JavaScript cannot obtain a primitive value from either `toString()` or `valueOf()`, so it throws a TypeError.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    toString: function() {
        console.log('toStirng...');
        return 90;
    },
    valueOf: function() {
        console.log('valueOf...');
        return 80;
    }
}

console.log(obj + '');
```

Accordingly, the code snippet above will convert `obj` to string because of `obj + ''`, so it should print:

```
toString...
90
```

But actually, it prints:

```
valueOf...
80
```

So what's wrong? Doesn't `obj + ''` convert `obj` to string?

Comment: `obj.toString()` returns expected result

Comment: Yes, @guest271314, but `obj + ''` will convert `obj` to string implicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As illustrated nicely in *[this](http://2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html)* article:

it is because +'' utilises the ToPrimitive(Number) internal method. If you run String(obj) you will receive the toString method result.